# Conformal Mapping on Extended complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the mapping $$f(z) : = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}\left( z + \frac{1}{z} \right), & z \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \{ 0 \}, \\
\infty, & z=0,\infty. 
\end{cases}$$ I am trying to find where $f$ is conformal. We know that a map $f$ is conformal at $z$ if $f$ is holomorphic at $z$ and $f'(z) \neq 0$. From our definition of $f$, it appears that $f$ is holomorphic for all $z \in \overline{\mathbb{C}}$. The derivative is given by $$f'(z) = 
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2z^2}, \forall z \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \{ 0 \}.$$ I am not sure how we would define $f'(0)$ and $f'(\infty)$ however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(a)=\infty$ then $f$ is conformal at $a$ if and only if $1/f$ is conformal at $a$. Similarly $f$ is conformal at $\infty$ if and only if $f(1/z)$ is conformal at $0$.